# How to stop repeating myself in Java

Tags: java, android

I use a method for more than one time in JavaScript by using callback method because JavaScript is an async language.

Example:

```
function missionOne () {
    sumCalculation(1, 2, function (result) {
        console.log(result) // writes 3
    })
}

function sumCalculation (param1, param2, callback) { 
  let result = param1 + param2
  // The things that take long time can be done here
  callback(result)
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to stop myself in Java?

Edit: I remove several sentences that make more complex the question.

Comment: I don't really get what is your question. Is it about getting results out of an `AsyncTask`? Or how to organize code? Could you please provide some code example that you would like to improve?

Comment: Are you writing an app for Android? Because AsyncTask is not part of the Java SDK, it is specific to Android's SDK.

Comment: Does not look like Java to me....

Comment: @efkan Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish, so we can provide you with a possible better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be reading too much into your question, but it seems that you're looking into how to handle asynchronous code in Android. There are a couple of native options (not considering any library). I'll focus on two, but keep in mind there are other options.

### AsyncTasks

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Before writing one, you need to know which type of parameters it will receive, the type of progress it will publish during computation and what is its return type. These types are define via the `AsyncTask` generic Parameters `AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>`. If you don't need them any of them, set them to `Void`

Here's the basic gist of using an `AsyncTask` to compute the sum of two `ints`:

```
public void sumCalculation (int param1, int param2, Callback callback) { 
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            int result = 0;
            for (Integer param : params) {
                result += param;
            }
            return result;                
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
            callback.onDone(integer);
        }

    }.execute(param1, param2);
}
```

`doInBackground`, as the name says, will execute a certain piece of code in a background thread. Please note that every `AsyncTask` will run on a `ThreadPool` of size 1, so they actually get in the way of other `AsyncTasks`.

`onPostExecute` brings the result back to the main thread, so you can update any UI componente. If you try to update the UI from a background thread, an exception will be thrown.

The down side of this particular example is the creation of a new AsyncTask every time that function is called.
Also you should use `AsyncTask` only if the task won't run for a very long time, couple of seconds at most.

### Thread and Handler

Another option suggested on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) is using a thread and a handler to communicate between the main thread and a background thread. Although this provides greater flexibility, it also requires more responsibility as you will be responsible for managing the communication yourself, picking the right time to kill your threads and how to recover when something goes bad.

As a rule of thumb, you should only go this way if you really need the extra flexibility.

The overall idea is to create your own Handler and override its `handleMessage` method.

```
  public class MyHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
            int messageType = inputMessage.what;
            Object extraData = inputMessage.obj;
            ...
        }
  }

  public class MyTask extends Thread {
       public static public int COMPUTATION_DONE = 0;
       private MyHandler handler;

       public MyTask(MyHandler handler) {
            this.handler = handler;
       }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your computation
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(COMPUTATION_DONE, your_result);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
  }
```

As you can see, this requiring parsing `inputMessage.what` and deciding what to do with it. Additionally, you need to cast `inputMessage.obj` to the right type and so on.

These are just two examples, but depending on what you're trying to do, you might need to dig deeper into `Services` or take a look at some reactive approach, such as `RxJava2`. However I encourage you to start with the basic before diving into something way more complicated.

Comment: I have a question, its about Picnic do you mind? @Edson

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy in Java.  To take your example above you can write it in Java like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(sumCalc(1,2));
}

private int sumCalc(int first, int second) {
  return first + second;
}
```

Comment: If I make intensive operations in sumCalc and if I use it in a method, is it work properly? I guess this code is not right way to rescue me from repeating myself. Can we turn it into a 'sync' method?

Comment: If I declare sumCalc method as 'synchronized'  does it work synchronously when I call it from another method?

Comment: The idea of 'repeating yourself' 'asynchronous code' and 'sychronized' methods are three very different things.  I think you have a lot to learn about java, and would benefit from reading more about it before asking too many more questions